# How Can I Maintain a Unique Identifier Amongst Multiple Database Tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have been tasked with creating history tables for an Oracle 11g database. I have proposed something very much like the record based solution in the first answer of this post [What is the best way to keep changes history to database fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749019/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-changes-history-to-database-fields)

Then my boss suggested that due to the fact that some tables are clustered i.e Some data from table 1 is related to table 2 (think of this as the format the tables were in before they were normalised), he would like there to be a version number which is maintained between all the tables at this cluster level. The suggested way to generate the version number is by using a SYS_GUID http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions153.htm.

I thought about doing this with triggers so when one of this tables is updated, the other tables version numbers are subsequently updated, but I can see some issues with this such as the following:

- How can I stop the trigger from one table, in turn firing the trigger for the other table?(We would end up calling triggers forever here)
- How can I stop the race conditions? (i.e When table 1 and 2 are updated at the same time, how do I know which is the latest version number?)

I am pretty new to Oracle database development so some suggestions about whether or not this is a good idea/if there is a better way of doing this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you're looking for is sequence: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

The tables could take the numbers from defined sequence independently, so no race conditions or triggers on your side should occur

Comment: A sequence is not applicable in this scenario as there can still be a race condition when I want to update the other tables to match the newly updated table's version number. The issue of synchronising this number between all of the related tables still exists, thanks for attempting to answer my question though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your first question is "No, you cannot.". The reason for this is that there's no way that users can stop a stated trigger. The only method I can imagine is some store of locking table, for example you create a intermediate table, and **select** the same row **for update** among your clustered tables. But this is really a bad way, as you've already mentioned in your second question. It will cause dreadful concurrency issue.

For your second question, you are very right. Different triggers for different original tables to update the same audit table will cause serious contention. It's wise to bear in mind the way triggers work that is they are committed when the rest of transaction commit. So if all related tables will update the same audit table, especially for the same row, simultaneously will render the rational paradigm unused. One benefit of the normalization is performance gain, as when you update different table will not content each other. But in this case if you want synchronize different table's operations in audit table. It will finally work like a flat file. So my suggestion would be trying your best to persuade your boss to use your original proposal.

But if your application always updates these clustered table in a transaction and write one audit information to audit table. You may write a stored procedure to update the entities first and write an audit at end of the transaction. Then you can use sequence to generate the id of audit table. It won't be any contention.